# How sum embedded dataframe columns in a dynamic R list?

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I am learning to work with lists.

How would I add all columns in a dynamic list with embedded dataframes, where for example I want to sum all columns named `First.allocation` in all sublists whose names begin with `Syria`? For example, in `List1` below, the function or formula would return a vector of (7,9,11,13,15) representing the columnar sums of the sublist `Syria_One` and sublist `Syria_Two` "First.allocation" columns.

As another example, in `List2` below, the function or formula would return a vector of (1,2,3,4,5) representing the `First.allocation` column of the only sublist in the list that begins with "Syria".

```
List1 <- list(
  Syria_One = data.frame(
    First.allocation = c(1,2,3,4,5),
    Second.numerator = rep(0,5),
    Second.allocation = rep(0,5)
  ),
  Syria_Two = data.frame(
    First.allocation = c(6,7,8,9,10),
    Second.numerator = rep(0,5),
    Second.allocation = rep(0,5)
  ),
  Tunisia = data.frame(
    First.allocation = rep(0.2,5),
    Second.numerator = rep(0,5),
    Second.allocation = rep(0,5)
  ),
  Total = data.frame(
    First.allocation = rep(1,5),
    Second.numerator = rep(0,5),
    Second.allocation = rep(0,5)
  )
)

List2 <- list(
  Syria_One = data.frame(
    First.allocation = c(1,2,3,4,5),
    Second.numerator = rep(0,5),
    Second.allocation = rep(0,5)
  ),
  Tunisia = data.frame(
    First.allocation = rep(0.2,5),
    Second.numerator = rep(0,5),
    Second.allocation = rep(0,5)
  ),
  Total = data.frame(
    First.allocation = rep(1,5),
    Second.numerator = rep(0,5),
    Second.allocation = rep(0,5)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal with this dynamically, you can define a function with 2 parameters:

- `regex`: the regular expression for list names
- `col`: the column names (or indices)

```r
fun <- function(lst, regex = "^Syria", col = 1) {
  Reduce(`+`, lapply(lst[grepl(regex, names(lst))], `[[`, col))
}

fun(List1)
# [1]  7  9 11 13 15

fun(List2)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

If you want to operate other lists except "Syria", or other columns except "First.allocation", you can modify these parameters when calling `fun()`.

Answer (score 2):

There may be more elegant approaches, but one approach is to use `lapply` to get the desired column (with `grep` to isolate those with "Syria"), then `do.call` to `cbind` the columns and finally `rowSums` to get the sum:

```
rowSums(do.call(cbind, lapply(List1[grepl("Syria", names(List1))], function(x) x[,1])))

# [1]  7  9 11 13 15
```

To break this down, since the above may be a bit confusing:

```
syria <- grepl("Syria", names(List1))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

List_Syria <- List1[syria]

#$Syria_One
#  First.allocation Second.numerator Second.allocation
#1                1                0                 0
#2                2                0                 0
#3                3                0                 0
#4                4                0                 0
#5                5                0                 0
#
#$Syria_Two
#  First.allocation Second.numerator Second.allocation
#1                6                0                 0
#2                7                0                 0
#3                8                0                 0
#4                9                0                 0
#5               10                0                 0

test1 <- lapply(List_Syria, function(x) x[,1])

#$Syria_One
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
#
#$Syria_Two
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10

test2 <- do.call(cbind, test1)

#     Syria_One Syria_Two
#[1,]         1         6
#[2,]         2         7
#[3,]         3         8
#[4,]         4         9
#[5,]         5        10

rowSums(test2)
#[1]  7  9 11 13 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum like-named elements (where like-named means prefix before the last `_`):

```r
f <- function(l) {
split(names(l), gsub("_.*", "", names(l))) |>
  lapply(\(x) Reduce(`+`, l[x]))
}

f(List1)

$Syria
  First.allocation Second.numerator Second.allocation
1                7                0                 0
2                9                0                 0
3               11                0                 0
4               13                0                 0
5               15                0                 0

$Total
  First.allocation Second.numerator Second.allocation
1                1                0                 0
2                1                0                 0
3                1                0                 0
4                1                0                 0
5                1                0                 0

$Tunisia
  First.allocation Second.numerator Second.allocation
1              0.2                0                 0
2              0.2                0                 0
3              0.2                0                 0
4              0.2                0                 0
5              0.2                0                 0
```

Then you can simply access any element and columns you would like:

```r
f(List1)$Syria$First.allocation
# [1]  7  9 11 13 15
```

This is flexible enough to work if you also had "Tunisia_One" and "Tunisia_Two", etc in the same list.